# How to play a video in full-screen mode on mobile

Tags: jquery, youtube, fancybox, lightbox, vimeo

I'm using **[Fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/)** plugin for playing a video on modal. The requirement of playing video on desktop and tablet are fulfilled with this easily. But on mobile, instead of showing a modal window, the video should play in full-screen mode automatically when click the link. I tried disabling the plugin in mobile, to hope if youtube opens it in full screen mode automatically when a user redirects. But didn't work.

How can I achieve this? Or is that actually possible?

**Here is the jQuery**

```
$(function () {
        var jWindow = $(window);
        $(".youtube-media").click(function () {
            if (jWindow.width() <= 768)
                return;
            $.fancybox({
                'padding': 2, 'autoScale': true, 'transitionIn': 'none', 'transitionOut': 'none', 'title': this.title,
                'width': 600, 'height': 340, 'href': this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'v/'),
                'type': 'swf', 'swf': {
                    'wmode': 'transparent',
                    'allowfullscreen': 'true'
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

**And here is the HTML Code**

```
<a class="youtube-media" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=opj24KnzrWo">Play Video</a>
```

Comment: when you said "mobile" do you mean apple devices? if so you can't play `swf` type of content, use youtube's `embed` mode instead.

Comment: let's say not for apple devices, but for those which support swf type of content. is that actually possible in this scenario?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For a cross-device compatibility, I would rather use youtube in its `embed` format so you can open it as `iframe` with this html format :

```
<a class="youtube-media" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/L9szn1QQfas?autoplay=1&wmode=opaque&fs=1">youtube</a>
```

Notice that I also added the parameter `&fs=1` to add *fullscreen* support.

Then this script should do the trick :

```
$(".youtube-media").on("click", function (e) {
    var jWindow = $(window).width();
    if ( jWindow <= 768 ) {
        return;
    }
    $.fancybox({
        href: this.href,
        type: "iframe" // when using embed format
    });
    return false;
});
```

See this **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Gpp5w/)** in small format so youtube should be fullscreen (the `results` area when smaller than 768px). Then see this **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Gpp5w/show/)** in big format so youtube displays in fancybox.

**NOTE** : `.on()` requires jQuery v1.7+

Comment: Cool idea to open video for phones straight from video service website, but actually autoplay doesn't work in iOs and anroid. And your example has no viewport, so it couldn't be tested properly on devices.

Comment: @Rantiev : as far as I know, videos don't autoplay on either iOS or Android. That's a feature for mobile devices since you don't want to waste your bandwidth on an unwanted autoplayed video, do you?

Comment: Yep, have knew that just right before read this comment ) Thank You anyway! They did that right way, this makes sense.